# JQuery issue (major) with IE - all versions

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

This only happens with IE (all versions), on line 1120 in
jquery-1.2.6.js I get the following error:

```
Line 1120:
Invalid Property Value
```

The line in the js file is the following:

```
elem[name] = value;
```

It is inside attr: `function( elem, name, value )`

Does anybody have a problem similar to this?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Just load the library on the page?  Or are you using it for anything?

Answer (score 6):

If [this](http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-en/browse_thread/thread/3ef3a830916b2fbb) is also you, it sounds like you're trying to change the CSS of the element rather than give it an attribute.

If that is the case then try this instead;

```
jQuery.css('color', 'inherit');
```

Answer (score 0):

This error can also occur if you call jQuery.css with an invalid attribute value, such as:

```
$('div.foo').css('padding-left', 'NaNpx');
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is IE-only because you are probably trying to set something like "min-height" which exists in (a proper CSS implenting) browser like Firefox, but not in a (demon spawned fiend of a) browser like Internet Explorer.  I ran in to the same issue using jQuery's own dialog UI function.

I was a huge proponent of jQuery before this, but this has really put some egg on its face.

Comment: Did you ever get any traction on this issue?  I'm having this problem with the jQuery UI dialog as well, and I'm getting nowhere trying to fix it.

Comment: Honestly, I never followed up on it.  I'd suggest asking on the jQuery UI list.

(Also I should mention that, despite my earlier "egg on its face" comment, I briefly met some of the main jQuery UI devs at jQuery Conf, and they struck me as being good developers.  I think the problem is just that jQuery UI is MUCH less mature than jQuery, but everyone, myself included, expects it to be just as mature as the main library.  In time I hope/expect it will eventually catch up.)

Comment: This was fixed in 1.6.2 (Jun 30, 2011)